Laravel export csv file having japanese file name
While I am downloading csv file in my laravel project, the file name which is in japanese is printed like ___.csv.
This is the file download part
 $currentDate = Carbon::now()->format('Ymd');
        $fileName = '【' . $selectedCategory->title . '】' . $headquarterName->title . '_' . $currentDate . '_虎の巻利用状況.csv';
        $filePath = storage_path('app/'.$fileName);
        // csv download
        $csvFile = fopen(storage_path('app/' . $fileName), 'w');
        $bom = chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191);
        fwrite($csvFile, $bom);
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
        fputcsv($csvFile, $this->getHeaderRow($contents));
        foreach ($contents as $data) {
            $dataRow = $this->getDataRow($data);
            $this->customFputcsv($csvFile, $dataRow);
        }
        fclose($csvFile);
        return Response::download($filePath, $fileName);

This is file name is storage
file stored in storage
And this is the file which is downloaded in my device:
file downloaded in my device
Here we can see that japanese charecters are printed like ____
I need solution from here.

I don't think that's a problem of Php as it should be sending the correct filename.

@Fravadona , what might be the cause of this? Do you have any idea?

which is downloaded in my device, What's the device? A phone? It's probably the device that can't store those characters in the disk

@Fravadona its windows I also tried it in macbook but the problem is same

@subash don't post images. if the $selectedCategory \ $headquarterName is null then won't print.

@francisco here actual problem is Japanese character if $selectedCategory and $headquarterName is in English then its fine

@francisco if file name is 国ヤtestヱル.csv then it will download as '_ test _.csv'

BTW, why do you use header instead of laravel's response->header?

@Fravadona I also tried with response->header but not worked.

Finally i found solution.
This is not working because this is inside livewire file. I tried same thing from the controller and its worked.

Finally i found solution. This is not working because this is inside livewire file. I tried same thing from the controller and its worked
